# Why are methods in thread not running?

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is a subsequent question to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524798/what-is-wrong-with-my-method-signature-when-passing-method-pointer-to-pthread-cr).

I pass a struct ...

```
struct threadDirectives_t {
    int block;
    medianfilter mFilter;
};
```

... to my thread's method `computeSignalBlock`. However, it does not output any text. Neither with `cout`, nor with `printf`.

I only get this console output:

```
Start computing filtered results.
Started thread 0.
Started thread 1.
```

Why is that?

```
void medianfilter::computeFilteredResults(vector<float> _signals, int _nThreads,
        int _windowSize, bool _isParallel) {

    printf("Start computing filtered results.\n");

    // Set instanz variables.
    originalSignalVector = _signals;
    nThreads = _nThreads;
    windowSize = _windowSize;
    isParallel = _isParallel;

    // Create the threads,
    pthread_t threads[nThreads];
    threadDirectives_t threadDirectivesArr[nThreads];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    // Initialize and set thread joinable
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    int threatResponse;

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        threadDirectives_t iTD;
        iTD.block = i;
        iTD.mFilter = *this;
        threadDirectivesArr[i] = iTD;

        threatResponse = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, computeSignalBlock,
                (void *) &threadDirectivesArr[i]);
        if (threatResponse) {
            printf("Error: unable to create thread: %d\n", threatResponse);
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("Started thread %d.\n",  i);
    }

}

void *medianfilter::computeSignalBlock(void *threadDirectives) {
    threadDirectives_t* thisPtr =
            reinterpret_cast<threadDirectives_t*>(threadDirectives);

    cout << "test";
    //TODO I need  access to instance variables!!
    // 1) Get my block to compute.
    printf("This is computation block # %d\n", thisPtr->block);
    // 2) Compute block.
}
```

Building the project completes with warnings.

```
12:55:39 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project SSExercise3 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/medianfilter.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"src/medianfilter.d" -MT"src/medianfilter.d" -o "src/medianfilter.o" "../src/medianfilter.cpp"
../src/medianfilter.cpp: In static member function ‘static void* medianfilter::computeSignalBlock(void*)’:
../src/medianfilter.cpp:79:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
Finished building: ../src/medianfilter.cpp

Building target: SSExercise3
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -pthread -o "SSExercise3"  ./src/SSExercise3.o ./src/medianfilter.o ./src/reader.o   
Finished building target: SSExercise3


12:55:40 Build Finished (took 1s.204ms)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Since you are using C++11 please consider to use std::thread.

Comment: The warning text says it well: you did not have a return statement in `medianfilter::computeSignalBlock` which is declared to return a pointer-to-void.

Comment: You probably required `pthread_join` since other the program terminates without completing the thread job.

Comment: After @AlexeyKukanov comment you should probably edit your code and then share with us your result after recompiling.

Comment: @sfrehse True, Failed to wait. Please post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks to all for the extra hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to call `pthread_join`. The question is also related to [pthread - How to start running a new thread without calling join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184627/pthread-how-to-start-running-a-new-thread-without-calling-join)